# Write access to project denied when trying to deploy to Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I have been working on a project for a couple of months and when I tried to deploy updates today I was met with the following error: `HTTP Error: 403, Write access to project was denied`

This is not the first time I have called firebase deploy for this project but I haven't had any issues before.

The relevant section of the log generated with `firebase deploy --debug`:

```
[2023-02-14T09:05:36.343Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/galimbang-192cf/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl [none]
[2023-02-14T09:05:37.947Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/galimbang-192cf/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl 403
[2023-02-14T09:05:37.947Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2/projects/galimbang-192cf/locations/us-central1/functions:generateUploadUrl {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Write access to project 'galimbang-192cf' was denied","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}


There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
⚠  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 403, Write access to project 'galimbang-192cf' was denied 

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Write access to project 'galimbang-192cf' was denied
[2023-02-14T09:05:37.950Z] Error Context: {
  "body": {
    "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Write access to project 'galimbang-192cf' was denied",
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 403
  }
}
```

I should also note that this project uses the Next.JS firebase integration.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, i noticed it was after my plan was downgraded to spark due to inactivity. After upgrading again, the permissions error stopped appearing. Hope this helps